# Need Fixed Header in ios7+

Tags: javascript, ios, html, css, jquery-mobile

I need the header should be fixed at the top even when the keyboard appears. 
Whenever i click on the text box the keypad comes up and the whole page including the header is moving to the top and it can be seen only by scrolling the page. I have set the position as fixed for header. What is the best solution to fix this in ios7+ without using Objective C. 
We have tried with whatever solution that has been provided here :

[Transition to iOS 7: correct viewport setting for jQuery/iPhone Webapps viewed on iPads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18892491/transition-to-ios-7-correct-viewport-setting-for-jquery-iphone-webapps-viewed-o)

But it didn't work. Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: check this one maybe helpfull http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16375557/fixed-header-scrolls-drags-in-jquery-mobile and this also https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/issues/5532

Answer (score 1):

There seem to be no way. iOS just makes all that is fixed - absolute while keyboard is up.