# when text focus (keyboard open) the fixed header hide(gone)

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, jquery-mobile, cordova

In my phonegap application for android(4.2.2) using jquery mobile(v 1.3.2) when the text box is focused (keyboard is open/show) at the time the jquery mobile **FIXED** header hide never visible again.Here is the sample code.

```
<!-- header start -->
    <div data-role="header" id="header" data-position="fixed" data-tap-toggle="false">
        <h4>Stop Card</h4>

        <div class="ui-btn-left">
            <a data-role="button" data-icon="check" id="save" >Lagre</a>
        </div>
        <div class="ui-btn-right">
            <a data-role="button" data-icon="delete" id="stopCardcancel" >Avbryt</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- header end -->
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using this you can fix the header issue `data-hide-during-focus="false"`. This will fix the header.

Try like this

```
<!-- header start -->
    <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed" data-tap-toggle="false" data-hide-during-focus="false" data-transition="none">
        <h4>Stop Card</h4>

        <div class="ui-btn-left">
            <a data-role="button" data-icon="check" id="save" >Lagre</a>
        </div>
        <div class="ui-btn-right">
            <a data-role="button" data-icon="delete" id="stopCardcancel" >Avbryt</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- header end -->
```

Note: Only in JQM 1.3.2

Comment: Worked for V 1.4.5

Answer (score 0):

Looks the repository, is an open issue ['fixed toolbars unfix after softkeyboard #5556'](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/issues/5556)

Perhaps this [answer for another stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16378107/3619619) question can help you.

Comment: I tried the stackoverflow answer(iscroll) but still the same the header is not fixed yet.

Comment: As I said It's an open issue :(

Answer (score 0):

Some times `data-position="fixed"` will not work properly, so give `position:fixed` for **ui-header** class.

```
.ui-header
{position:fixed;}
```